# Can't create Facebook AdSet

Tags: c#, facebook, api

I can't create new ad set, i got this message.
(FacebookApiException - #100) Invalid parameter

My code :

```
    dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
    parameters.name = title;
    parameters.billing_event = "IMPRESSIONS";
    parameters.optimization_goal = "POST_ENGAGEMENT";
    parameters.daily_budget = "2000";
    parameters.campaign_group_id = groupis;
    parameters.targeting = (dynamic)(new ExpandoObject());
    parameters.targeting.age_max = 65;
    parameters.targeting.age_min = 25;
    parameters.targeting.geo_locations = (dynamic)(new ExpandoObject());
    parameters.targeting.geo_locations.countries = new List<string>();
    parameters.targeting.geo_locations.countries.Add("US");
    dynamic res = fb.Post("/v2.4/act_" + adsid + "/adcampaigns", parameters);
```

Comment: Not a pro with the Ads API, but have you checked the documentation that your parameters are actually correct and valid? Once you're sure that all is set up correct, run the same request using cURL or the Graph API Explorer for example. If this still persists, report a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `access_token`, like this:

```
   var fb = new FacebookClient();

   dynamic parameters = new ExpandoObject();
   parameters.access_token = access_token;
   parameters.name = "RaedAddset2";
   parameters.optimization_goal = "REACH";
   parameters.billing_event = "IMPRESSIONS";
   parameters.campaign_status = "PAUSED";
   parameters.bid_amount = "5";
   parameters.daily_budget = "2000";
   parameters.campaign_group_id = campaign_group_id;
   parameters.targeting = new ExpandoObject();
   parameters.targeting.age_max = 65;
   parameters.targeting.age_min = 25;
   parameters.targeting.geo_locations = new ExpandoObject();
   parameters.targeting.geo_locations.countries = new List<string>();
   parameters.targeting.geo_locations.countries.Add("JO");
   var res = fb.Post("/v2.4/act_" + acount_id + "/adcampaigns", parameters);
```